# Tablesort Reload Table Data on Click using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tablesorter

I'm trying to reload the table data (rows/TRs) when the user clicks a link, I can add more/append? the data but I cannot seem to delete the old table data before inserting the new table data.
(BTW: the updatetable.php contains all of the (TR's) for that table)

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$(function() {


$("#append").click(function() { 

var test;
   $.get('updatetable.php', function(data) {
      test = data;
$("#tablesorter-demo").remove();
$("#tablesorter-demo").append(test);
$("#tablesorter-demo").trigger.update(); // <--- I think that error is here, I tried to take out the trigger. but it still doesn't work ?

alert(test);

//return false; 

   });
});
```

The href code is: `<a id="append" href="#">Refresh Page</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

    $("#append").click(function(e) { 

        e.preventDefault();

        $.get('updatetable.php', function(data) {
            $("#tablesorter-demo").find('tbody').html('').append(data);
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You wouldn't know how I can add the zebra filter to it and also keep the sort order so each time the data reloads it doesn't change the sort order for the visitor so that they don't have to click on the up/down arrow again. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I would probably need some more context. If you create a jsbin I can take a look.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this see this also PLEASE: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html Notice how when you sort the rows and then refresh the page the sort order is still the same, that is what I would like to do in my tablesort also up and down arrows are done for sorting in the jsbin example?

Comment: I also added an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bkMY3/ As you can see the sort, zebra, and sort does not work, and the updatable.php I cannot include but it would contain the updated copy of all the (TR's) for that table,  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Here's a modified version that uses the jsfiddle api to update the table when the button is clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/5PVqc/2/

Comment: Ok so I changed      url: '/echo/json/', to my updatetable.php page and what do I do with the          table: '<tr> <td>Smith</td><td>Frank</td><td>fsmith@yahoo.com</td><td>$50.00</td> <td>http://www.frank.com</td></tr><tr><td>Jones</td><td>Frank</td><td>fjones@yahoo.com</td><td>$50.00</td> <td>http://www.frank.com</td></tr>',   do I comment this out ?

Comment: Just comment out the entire $.ajax function and uncomment the $.get function

Answer (score 1):

@Adam Putinski Not if one is using Internet Explorer then it looks like this code will not work the table and rows show but nothing else can be done with them, also the    $('[title!=""]').qtip({
}); will only work until the user loads the data from the updatetable.php page then it will not work anymore ?