# Make tablesorter post column name instead of column number

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using [motties tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter), and it works great. I am using the tablesorterPager plugin, and have a lot of columns due to customer requirements.

When the search and/or filtering takes place, it is by the *column number* - I want it to be by the column id. Or more precisely, by a string id. Can this be done somehow?

I went through a heap of docs and examples, but it all seems to end up with the tablesorter posting a query string like this:

```
?size=50&page=0&filter[18]=Apple&column
```

So, column 18 should contain the word 'Apple'. It would be just so much easier to follow the code from frontend to backend if the 18 would be the string 'ItemDescription' instead! Something like this:

```
?size=50&page=0&filter[ItemDescription]=Apple&column
```

Can it be done without hacking tablesorter too much?

Comment: Try the [`customAjaxUrl` callback](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-customajaxurl)

Comment: Hi Mottie, I found that callback today, it works perfectly. The only bad thing with tablesorter is it can do everything, so takes some time to find the right pitch. :) Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: I have enough points ;) you post the answer and I'll upvote you!

Comment: This is a good similar question I found after asking this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482544/tablesorterpager-plug-in-how-to-integrate-with-other-controls